# How do I get each button to output their own number

Tags: python, for-loop, numbers, range, calculator

This is only a small part of the code, and i am new to python, but i'm making a calculator and trying to use a for loop to make the number buttons. All of my buttons are placed in the correct place, with the right numbers on them, but when i  click any of them they all output the number nine.

```
    for number in range(1, 10):
        row= math.ceil(number/3) + 5
        col = (number-1) % 3
        num_btn = Button(self.root, text=str(number), height=3, width=9, bg='white', relief='solid', borderwidth=1)
        num_btn.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=1, pady=1)
        num_btn.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.putDigit (event, number))
```

I think it has something to do with the (event, number)) in the last line, as if i change that to (number-1) it will output 8, so how do I make the buttons output the correct numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By binding an event to a lambda function, all the variables used in the lambda function are evaluated only when the function is called as the button is pressed, and in this case `number` becomes `9` after this setup loop, so when any of the buttons is pressed `number` is evaluated as `9`.

Instead, you should localize `number` by wrapping your lambda function in another lambda function that returns your lambda function with the number you want localized as an argument:

```
for number in range(1, 10):
    row= math.ceil(number/3) + 5
    col = (number-1) % 3
    num_btn = Button(self.root, text=str(number), height=3, width=9, bg='white', relief='solid', borderwidth=1)
    num_btn.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=1, pady=1)
    num_btn.bind('<Button-1>', (lambda x: lambda event: self.putDigit (event, x))(number))
```

Or, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has helpfully pointed out, you can also make `number` a default parameter value so that it's evaluated when your lambda function is defined:

```
    num_btn.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, x=number: self.putDigit (event, x))
```

Comment: Or you could just pass it as a default parameter.